# Cakephp inheritng controller variable in function from another function variable

Tags: php, cakephp

is there a way we can get variable from another function for the current function in controller and user set function to use in corresponding view file?

Sorry guys I meant passing view file variable to another view file...Below is the code...

```
function get_random_color()
{
        $c="";
    for ($i = 0; $i<6; $i++)
    {
        $c .=  dechex(rand(0,15));
    }
    return "#$c";
} 
$i = 0;//debug($trips);
foreach ($trips as $trip) {
    $colour = get_random_color();

    $numItems = count($trip['trip']['coords']);
    if($numItems > 3){
        $x = 0;
        echo 'var flightPlanCoordinates'.$i.' = [';
        foreach($trip['trip']['coords'] as $coords) {

            if($x+1 == $numItems) {
                echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$coords['latitude'].','.$coords['longitude'].') ';
            }
            else {
                echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$coords['latitude'].','.$coords['longitude'].'), ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        /*
        for($x = 0; $x<sizeof($trip['trip']['coords']); $x++) {
            echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$trip['trip']['coords']['latitude'].','.$trip['trip']['coords']['longitude'].'), ';
        }*/


        echo ']; ';
        echo 'var flightPath'.$i.' = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates'.$i.',
        strokeColor: "'.$colour.'",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4
        });';

        echo 'flightPath'.$i.'.setMap(map);';

        $i++;   
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not good style to do many logic stuff in the view because that will break MVC pattern.Just try to do it in your controller or model,and keep the view as simple as you can.

Comment: are you trying to pass php variables into javascript here? Why not do the manipulation that you need to do in the controller, build a json object and pass it to the view and parse it with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a requestAction, although it is considered the slower way to get at that data. If you give more details I might be able to give you a better answer.

```
$this->requestAction('/posts/list');
```

more on requestActions here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/991/requestAction

Comment: `If used without caching requestAction can lead to poor performance. It is rarely appropriate to use in a controller or model.`

Comment: I agree and wrote as much in the first line, but the description given, moving one variable from one controller to another is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Configure class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/42/The-Configuration-Class) if you need a global variable in this situation,request action should be a bad choice.

Comment: This would only work if he is in the other controller first. If it is something requiring dynamic data this wouldn't work. I interpreted this more as I'm in posts and need something from tags that I have a function for in tags.

Unless I have using the configure wrong you could just as easily set a session variable.

Comment: @Matt,I think request action still can be avoided even the data is dynamic--in your case ,the function can be placed in the tag's model so that we can get the data by using tag-model in post-controller.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to play with the configure class more. I most often use it for debug toggling and in a few other case by case situations.